# Heroku: Exception "No modume name ..." in worker process

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Django app on Heroku, after running `git push heroku master`, then `heroku open` fails with an exception.

`heroku logs` shows:

```
[2018-01-21 05:25:17 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928006+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call      last):
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928007+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python /lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928009+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928010+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928011+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928012+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928013+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928014+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928015+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928016+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928016+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928018+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928018+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928019+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928020+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928021+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/mysite/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928023+00:00 app[web.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928023+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928024+00:00 app[web.1]:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928025+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928026+00:00 app[web.1]:     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928027+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928028+00:00 app[web.1]:     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928029+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928030+00:00 app[web.1]:     module = import_module(entry)
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928031+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928032+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(name)
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928033+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named taggit
2018-01-21T05:25:17.928163+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-01-21 05:25:17 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2018-01-21T05:25:17.962433+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-01-21 05:25:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2018-01-21T05:25:17.962513+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-01-21 05:25:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2018-01-21T05:25:18.038138+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2018-01-21T05:25:18.046911+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I am unable to figure out what is causing this eror, please someone guide me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImportError: No module named taggit`: the Python process couldn't find `taggit` module. I assume you are using django-taggit: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-taggit.

Normally, Heroku accepts `requirements.txt` as a list of dependencies. Add a line `django-taggit~=0.22.2` to the file, commit it, and push to Heroku.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Do you have any idea why button clicks and javascripts functions are not working after i deployed django app on heroku

Comment: You can create a new question with code snippets. Stackoverflow will help you.